# Where can the 'Fat32 Format' utility be downloaded from ? (shown in picture)

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, filesystems, download, file-download

[image]

I know this is a silly question (if not a downright stupid one)

Where can the Fat32 Format utility be downloaded from ?

I obviously tried using Google but the only website I could find was [this](https://en.softonic.com/download/fat32-format/windows)

which was odd considering it's supposedly free

I followed the Download button but the website didn't download anything or display any messages about the Download process

I tried using advanced google search to filter out specific phrases but it didn't work

I have windows 7 ultimate

---

It's not the topic of the question but here's the background story:

I have a 64GB USB drive that is NOT formated to FAT32 file system type, I need to change it to that file system type so that I can make it into a bootable ISO USB drive that is compatible with my computer's old and outdated BIOS (motherboard GR1M-VS3)

Comment: Can you not just use the in-built format utility by right clicking the drive and selecting Format...?

Comment: @RobbieW. Built in formatting tool has been limited to <30gb for fat32 disks since Windows XP or earlier.

Comment: An alternative but related tool would be `SDFormatter` which I believe should still be available.

Comment: Fat32 option not available in dropdown menu, only exFAT and NTFS. Not even using cmd worked either ( format /FS:FAT32 H: )

Comment: the BIOS doesn't care about what filesystem your drive has. It doesn't even know partitions. It simply loads the MBR and runs it. Anyway any 3rd party disk partitioners are able to format FAT32 drives larger than 32GB

Answer (score 0):

The image you linked gives the following URL as a donation page:
www.ridgecrop.demon.co.uk/guiformat.htm

This seems to redirect straight to the page for GuiFormat, what looks to be a GUI version of the Fat32 Formatter.

However, from there, it is easy to link back to [this page](http://www.ridgecrop.demon.co.uk/index.htm?fat32format.htm) to download the Fat32 Formatter (link is a bit down the page where it says "Now download a copy of fat32format.")

Comment: I din't see your answer until I had submit on mine. We both had the same idea :-)

Answer (score 0):

The thing is actually called GUIFormat and is available directly from the maker at [thsi website](http://www.ridgecrop.demon.co.uk/index.htm?guiformat.htm)
You didn't look closely enough at the screenshot. The web-site of the maker is shown at the bottom.